# Why isn't WiX Burn evaluating a Condition based on VersionMsi?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix3.8

I'm working on the installer for a product that still supports Windows Server 2003, at least for a little longer.  I want to ensure that Windows Installer 4.5 or higher is present, because the included SQL Server Express setup will fail with an older version of Windows Installer.  I added the following [Condition](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/condition.html) to my [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) 3.8 Burn [Bundle](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html), but it isn't triggering.

```
<bal:Condition Message="This software requires Windows Installer 4.5.">
  <![CDATA[VersionMsi >= v4.5]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

I have run `msiexec -?` on the virtual machine where I am testing the installation to verify that Windows Installer 3.01 is present.  I made sure to include the `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` declaration and reference WixBalExtension.dll.  I have also verified that the following similar condition works, allowing me to verify that .NET Framework 4 is installed.

```
<bal:Condition Message="This software requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.">
  <![CDATA[NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

`VersionMsi` is one of the [Burn built-in variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html), so I'm not sure why my condition isn't working.  [This exchange](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/VersionMsi-and-Bundle-Conditions-td7583278.html) seems to say that I'm on the right track, but I'm not there yet.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived at this due to a 1708 error then you might require a specific MSI 4.5 update.

In these situations you need to excplicitly test the version of msi.dll rather then the VersionMSI variable.

See the click-once bootstrapper package manifest for Windows Installer 4.5 in the Windows SDK for the proper condition for each MSI update package.